# numbering in pandas on incremental order and also without considering a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Input dataframe:

```
load1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],

                   })
```

`Rank`: Sort B values on descending order and give rank from 1 on incremental order

`Rank_without_a_column`: Leave the first column of the descending order sorted B and give rank from 1 on incremental order

`Exact_Rank`: Give correct ranking as shown in Exact rank on Expected Output

`Exact_Rank_Without_a_column`:

Expected Output:

```
        A   B   Rank    Rank_without_a_column  Exact_Rank  Exact_Rank_Without_a_column   

    0   a   5   1   Null                          1          Null
    1   b   5   2   1                             1           1
    2   c   5   3   2                             1           1
    3   d   4   4   3                             2           2
    4   e   4   5   4                             2           2
    5   f   4   6   5                             2           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need series of rank methods as:

```
load1.sort_values('B',ascending=False,inplace=True)
load1['Rank'] = load1['B'].rank(ascending=False,method='first').astype(int)
load1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
load1.loc[1:,'Rank_without_a_column'] = load1.loc[1:,'B'].rank(ascending=False,method='first')
load1['Exact_Rank'] = load1['B'].rank(ascending=False,method='dense').astype(int)
load1.loc[1:,'Exact_Rank_Without_a_column'] = load1.loc[1:,'Exact_Rank'].rank(ascending=True,method='dense')


load1

    A   B   Rank    Rank_without_a_column   Exact_Rank  Exact_Rank_Without_a_column
0   b   5   1       NaN                     1           NaN
1   d   5   2       1.0                     1           1.0
2   e   5   3       2.0                     1           1.0
3   a   4   4       3.0                     2           2.0
4   c   4   5       4.0                     2           2.0
5   f   4   6       5.0                     2           2.0
```

Comment: a small followup question load1.loc[1:,'Exact_Rank'] how to do it for between values

Comment: @YogeshSP If you want to do between `2:4` indices use `load1.loc[2:4,'Exact_Rank']` where only those values will be retrieved or If assigned. If you have multiple like `2:4` and `7:10` then use numpy method `np.r_[2:4,7:10]`.